# How can React's lifecycle method's be written in Typescript with es6 arrow notation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

The following code will produce the typescript error:

> "Class 'Component' defines instance member
>   function 'componentWillMount', but extended class 'Pages' defines it
>   as instance member property."

```
  interface IProps {
     history?: any
  }

  interface IState {
    mql: MediaQueryList
    sidebarDocked: boolean
    sidebarOpen: boolean
  }

export class Pages extends Component<IProps, IState> {

  componentWillMount = () => {
    mql.addListener(this.mediaQueryChanged)
    this.setState({ mql: mql, sidebarDocked: mql.matches })
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.state.mql.removeListener(this.mediaQueryChanged)
  }
  ...
}
```

However, a non-lifecycle method *will* function properly using es6 arrow notation:

```
  mediaQueryChanged = () => {
    const { setDockMode } = this.props
    this.setState({ sidebarDocked: this.state.mql.matches })
  }
```

The error informs me that Pages is a class that defines an instance member. So my question essentially boils down to "how can typescript instance members be written using es6 arrow notation?"

I should also mention that regular function notation *does* function properly, but then I have to concern myself with binding this. So far, I have been successful in only using arrow notation with React, but Typescript seems to ruin that.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking more at Typescript's documentation, I found that adding `private` in front of the lifecycle method's will cause the errors to vanish. However, I still do not know why this is. The private keyword, from my understanding restricts access to the class by outside method's. That is all I know for now. Will update when I have more information.

**Update 1**

Appending `private` to the lifecycle methods does **not** solve the issue. The error instead movies to the class name and states:

> Class 'Pages' incorrectly extends base class 'Component'.   Property 'componentWillMount' is private in type
>   'Pages' but not in type 'Component'.

I went into react typescript types in the node_modules folder (index.d.ts) and found where the interface for `Component` is defined:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S, SS> { }
```

I see that it extends the ComponentLifecycle interface:

```
interface ComponentLifecycle<P, S, SS = any> extends NewLifecycle<P, S, SS>, DeprecatedLifecycle<P, S> {
    componentDidMount?(): void;
    shouldComponentUpdate?(nextProps: Readonly<P>, nextState: Readonly<S>, nextContext: any): boolean;
    **componentWillUnmount?(): void;**
    componentDidCatch?(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo): void;
}
```

In that interface, `componentWillUnmount` is defined as:

```
componentWillUnmount?(): void;
```

So, my question is, why does typescript not recognize `componentWillUnmount? = (): void => {};` as an alternative to `componentWillUnmount?(): void;`